# How to display latitude,longtitude,Heading in phonegap

Tags: jquery, android, cordova

I want to display the latitude,longtitude,Heading in same application using phonegap.i tried the phonegap same program.if i get latitude,longtude,i couldnt get heading is null.is there any way?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Compass Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.3.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/compass.css"/>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
       // The watch id references the current `watchHeading`
    var watchID = null;


    // Wait for PhoneGap to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // PhoneGap is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        var options = { frequency: 500 };
        watchID = navigator.compass.watchHeading(onSuccess, onError, options);
        //watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);


    }

/*
    // Start watching the compass
    //
    function startWatch() {
         // Update compass every 3 seconds
        var options = { frequency: 500 };

        watchID = navigator.compass.watchHeading(onSuccess, onError, options);
    }

    // Stop watching the compass
    //
    function stopWatch() {
        if (watchID) {
            navigator.compass.clearWatch(watchID);
            watchID = null;
        }
    }
*/
    // onSuccess: Get the current heading
    //
    function onSuccess(position) {
        var element = document.getElementById('ang');
        var deg_heading = document.getElementById('heading');
        //var lat = position.coords.latitude; 
        //var lng = position.coords.longitude;
        var deg = position.magneticHeading;
        var actual_deg = 360;
        //var deg = '180';
        //alert ("lat/lng: "+lat+","+lng);
        deg_heading.innerHTML = 'Heading: ' + (actual_deg - deg)  + '&#176';// + " lat:"+lat+" long:"+lng;

        element.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(-"+ deg +"deg)";


    }

    // onError: Failed to get the heading
    //
    function onError(compassError) {
        alert('Compass error: ' + compassError.code);
    }

    </script>
  </head>
   <body>
   <!-- <button onclick="startWatch();">Start Watching</button>
    <button onclick="stopWatch();">Stop Watching</button> -->
    <div id="compass" class="comapss">
        <div class="compass_direction"><img id="ang" src="img/direction.png"/></div>
    </div>
    <div id="heading"></div>    
  </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, I've had to monitor navigator.compass for initialization in some of my projects.  Occasionally it won't exist until a bit after deviceReady fires.  I usually use something like this:

```
var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
   if( navigator.compass ) {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
      intervalId = navigator.compass.watchHeading(onSuccess, onError, options);
   }
}, 250);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function locationFinder() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        function success(pos) {
            current_lng = pos.coords.longitude;
            current_lat = pos.coords.latitude;
            console.log("longitude get" + current_lng);
            console.log("latitude get" + current_lat);
        }
        function fail(error) {
            console.log("error 2");
        }
        // Find the users current position. Cache the location for 5 minutes,
        // timeout after 6 seconds
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, fail, {
            maximumAge : 500000,
            enableHighAccuracy : true,
            timeout : 6000
        });
    } else {
        window.plugins.toast.showLongBottom("Please check GPS Setting",
                function(a) {
                    console.log('toast success: ' + a)
                }, function(b) {
                    console.log('toast error: ' + b)
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: Use this function and also add plugin of geolocation. Plugin Id is:- org.apache.cordova.geolocation  or using repository :-  https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation.git

Answer (score 0):

I leave this here because I wasted a full day with the same problem.
You are looking into the wrong API for getting the Orientation of the phone. The heading attribute in the geolocation is not the compas orientation but a direction calculated based on the movement of the phone. So if you are standing still heading is null. As soon you as you are moving the heading points into the direction of your movement. See this docu: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GeolocationCoordinates/heading

What you are looking for is the "deviceorientation" event. For iOS/Safari you have to manually request the feature first.
(This is Typescript code)

```html
const isIOS = !(
    navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/) &&
    navigator.userAgent.match(/AppleWebKit/)
);
if (isIOS) {
    (DeviceOrientationEvent as any).requestPermission()
        .then((response: any) => {
            if (response === "granted") {
                window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", this.receivedNewHeading, true);
            } else {
                alert("has to be allowed!");
            }
        })
        .catch(() => alert("not supported"));
} else {
    window.addEventListener("deviceorientationabsolute", this.receivedNewHeading, true);
}
```